# C# How to make UWP XAML button not show border on hover

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Here is my button:

```
    <Button
        x:Name="buttonClear"
        Width="74"
        Height="52"
        Margin="3,175,0,0"
        Padding="8,1,8,5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Content="C"
        FontSize="24"
        FontWeight="Normal"
        FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="Transparent"
        FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0"
        Style="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealStyle}"
        Click="ButtonClear_Click" />
```

As you can see, I have added:

```
FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="Transparent"
FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0"
```

I thought it would get rid of the gray border that shows when you hover your mouse pointer on the button. But it didn't work.

I also tried adding the following to App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver">Transparent</SolidColorBrush>
</Application.Resources>
```

Still no result. Do I have to reference the key somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just hide the border with `BorderThickness="0"`

Alternatively you can edit the full style of the button as suggested by visc.

Comment: @EsAMe, if the reply is helpful please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the full style of the `Button`. The full `Button` style has `VisualState` definition for hover. Just modify or remove its storyboard.

Look at this link and you will find the full default button style definition.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates

I personally create a resource dictionary file I import to all my pages and when I define new buttons I set the `BasedOn` to my modified button style in the resource dictionary.

Comment: I'm really not that advanced so I don't know how to do this correctly.